# get imageurl from picture library linked to lookup column in list

Tags: 2013, list, picture-library

I have list called "Employee" and it has lookup column called as "City". This lookup column is Connected to Picture libraray. I wish to retrieve imageurl from it. How to achieve it. I tried this so far but unable to get.

```
SPList list = spWeb.Lists["Employee"];
SPList picLibCity = spWeb.Lists["City"];

foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
   EmpList.Add(new EmpLinks
   {
       Title = item["Title"].ToString(),
       City= new SPFieldLookupValue(item["City"] as String).LookupValue
   });
}
```

Then i am trying following to get imageurl

```
foreach (var row in EmpList)
{
    if (row.City!= null)
    {
        string group = row.city;
        SPItem lookupItem = picLibCity.GetItemById(group.LookupId);
        string imageUrl = lookupItem["ImageURL"].ToString();
    }

 }
```

This is my EmpLinks Class

```
 internal class EmpLinks
 {
        public string Title { set; get; }
        public string City{ set; get; }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `SPList` you should use `SPPictureLibrary`. I mean

```
SPList picLibCity = (SPPictureLibrary) spWeb.Lists["City"];
```

And instead of `ImageURL`, you should use `ServerUrl`. I mean

```
foreach (var row in EmpList)
{
    if (row.City!= null)
    {
        string group = row.city;
        SPItem lookupItem = picLibCity.GetItemById(group.LookupId);
        string imageUrl = lookupItem["ServerUrl"].ToString();
    }

 }
```

## Full modified code

```
SPList list = spWeb.Lists["Employee"];
SPList picLibCity = (SPPictureLibrary) spWeb.Lists["City"];

foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
   EmpList.Add(new EmpLinks
   {
       Title = item["Title"].ToString(),
       City= new SPFieldLookupValue(item["City"] as String)
   });
}

foreach (var row in EmpList)
    {
        if (row.City!= null)
        {
            SPItem lookupItem = picLibCity.GetItemById(row.City.LookupId);
            string imageUrl = lookupItem["ServerUrl"].ToString();
        }

     }

internal class EmpLinks
 {
        public string Title { set; get; }
        public SPFieldLookupValue City{ set; get; }

 }
```

If you need absolute URL, then you can use `EncodedAbsUrl`. I mean

```
string imageUrl = lookupItem["EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();
```

Comment: i cant get Group.lookupId as Group is string

Comment: Try as per my modified code

Comment: I am trying now

Comment: i get url as /sites/mystie/City/myimg.PNG... how can i show this in image.. do i need to just retrieve server name and add this url or any other method

Comment: No. just use `string imageUrl = lookupItem["EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();`. I have updated the answer.